# To find an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Syntactically speaking, what does it mean to find an isomorphism?

Let $T: M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}^2$ given by $T(M) = (M_{11}, \text{tr}(M))$. Find an isomorphism between $\text{ker } T$ and $\text{im } T$.

One sees quickly that $\text{Im }T = \text{span}\{e_1, e_4\}$ and $\text{ker }T = \text{span}\{e_2, e_3\}$

If the goal is to find an isomorphism between the image and the kernel, does this simply mean to find a map between the image and kernel?

Comment: When one says to "find an isomorphism" it means to construct an explicit map which is a homomorphism between the two spaces, and is bijective.

Answer (score 0):

In this context the kernel of your map are those matrices with $M_{11}=0$ (which since they must be traceless means that $M_{22}$) is also $0$, and hence your kernel is the space spanned by
\begin{pmatrix}
0& 0\\
M_{21}&0\\
\end{pmatrix} and \begin{pmatrix}
0& M_{12}\\
0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}

Clearly $\mathbf{Q}^2$ is spanned by $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$, and the isomorphism would just result from sending one basis to the other.